# Refactoring tools for Oxygene

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, oxygene, remobjects

What refactoring tools are avaliable for Oxygene language in VS2012. AFAIK Resharper & Coderush do not work with it. So what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, the upcoming August 2013 release will introduce built-in refactoring. We're starting small ("Rename"), but more will come over time.

Comment: I can only say FINALLY! :D

Comment: I forgot to mention but I hope that it will contain the long overdue "Structural Highlighting"..

Comment: Refagtoring is not Structural Highlighting, no.